# How to get interest in programming especially in java and android

Tags: java, android

I am new in this community. I just completed my Btech in Computer science, I have interest towards programming especially java. I started studying java but i am little bit slow in logic and understanding the concepts. I have some good books of java but when doing the program i am losing my confidence because of the logic issues. I have some doubts

1. How can i improve my logical and coding skills
2. HOw to get real interest in programming.
3. Is there any shortcut for studying programming

Please provide some suggestions as i knew this forum has lots of good programmers. Please share ur thoughts and how you people improving ur logics.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: There are no shortcuts, but contributing to open source is always good experience.

Comment: Try posting this question to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: thank you for the reply.. could you please tell me how to contribute to open source projects. I have started my studies.

Comment: Find an open source project.  Join the mailing list.  Join discussions on the mailing list.

Comment: @LouisWasserman how a newbie could be able to contribute in open source until he/she isn't able to face any difficult logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfect way is to start with the language you love. The syntax you like. The things you know. For example, suppose you know C++ and you are a bit familiar with it. Of course, you had done any of the language before in BTECH. So, go start up with that. Go through some basics of that to intermediate. And, if you're new to programming, then don't jump towards deep nor visit the Forum's guide post until you face the same problem. Make simple programs. Ask experts for your problems and when you feels yeah I learnt so much from my self and community, start digging the complex scenerios of that language. (**Here, language can be any programming. For your case, Java**)

Whenever you got perfect in your own loving language, it would be easy for you to switch any of the language because all languages are same probably. Mostly, some syntax changes and some component, feature or etc changes.

Comment: could you please explain how you are getting the logic ,if u going through a specific program. ? I dont know my question is correct, coz i am a newbie.

Comment: See @aditi, did you learnt any programming language in your BTech? If yes, then ofcourse you worked with it too. You want to go through on Java now, right? So, first there are two things. Either, you are handy enough to learn the new language easily, else make your programming base from favorite language. How many language you know except java? C++ , php, C# or any? If so, then make your self strong over it first. This is because, all language have characteristics. Loops, Collections, Objects and etc. So, if you're good with `Programming Language`, then you can learn any new language easily.

Comment: Now i got the big picture. thank you :)

Comment: Pleasure. Please choose correct (Tick) if my answer helped you! Thanks good luck!

Answer (score 2):

1. Write code. Read code. Study code. Breath code.
2. If you aren't interested already then (1) will be a bit hard
3. No, you just have to put the time in and do it

At the end of the day, the real way to become a better programmer it to use your tools more and to research proper methods of using those tools. There are no short cuts, there is no go direct to go and collect $200.

As for interest in coding. I find that my interest for various projects waxes and wanes but at the end of the day, I still have a voracious apatite for solving problems and writing code. I don't know if that can be learned.

Comment: drink code, eat code, sleep code...? :p

Answer (score 0):

1) By practice and even more practicing.

2) Don't you have an interest you can combine this with? It's hard to find a hobby that can't use any software.

3) If there is a shortcut it's probably no good.

4) Why do something you're not interested in?

Comment: Yeah I have interest in programming, but i need to improve my interest on this field so my skills.

Answer (score 0):

first of all

*3. There is no shortcut

you have to be patience and passionate in order to learn coding.

*2. See thing in computer, and be curios how the engineers make things so easy and simple that any person can do much complex task in a seconds

and

*1. In order to improve your logic you need to keep coding, more you code more you get sharpen, solve **puzzles, and  maths problems**, and to learn good coding style **head first java** and **Head First Design Patterns** is the best book that I found, which I personally love to read.